# Bignum getting value Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to write a code which inherit of class Bignum , I don't know how to get the value of Bignum

```
  class BigNum
     # the metod should check if the a divide BigNum
     def divide?(a)
       # how to get the value of Bignum
       self %a == 0

     end

    end
```

Comment: It should work the way you have written it. edit: only the name of the class is wrong(thanks to Dmitryi Budnik's answer)

Comment: Be careful with `self %a`. In this case it won't hurt you, but you should always use the same spacing on both sides of operators unless you intend them to be unary operators (e.g. `a *b` becomes `a(*b)` but `a * b` becomes `a.*(b)`)

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby allows you to extend existing classes, you don't have to create your own class:

```
class Bignum
  def divide?(a)
    self %a == 0
  end
end
```

This adds a method divide? to the existing (built-in) class Bignum.

Answer (score 0):

Class name is `Bignum` not `BigNum`.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he wants to create his own BigNum class that inherits from Bignum (which is kind of confusing).